# Unable to parse option value "bpyramid"

Tags: ffmpeg, flag

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)
configuration: --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg-4.1/ --extra-cflags=-I/opt/ffmpeg-4.1/include --extra-ldflags='-L/opt/ffmpeg-4.1/lib -ldl' --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --extra-libs=-lpthread --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100

ffmpeg  -y -i /test-in.mp4 -codec:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -threads 0 -codec:v libx264 -b:v 3000k -minrate 2400k -maxrate 4500k -bufsize 6000k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 9 -trellis 1 -refs 3 -bf 3 -deinterlace -coder 1 -me_range 24 -g 25 -keyint_min 25 -r 25 -sc_threshold 0 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 0         -qmax 40 -qdiff 4 -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9         -psy 1 -fast-pskip 1    -flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8     -pix_fmt yuv420p -y /test-out.mp4
```

I get error

```
[aac @ 0x466dec0] [Eval @ 0x7fffbc209f40] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'bpyramid'
[aac @ 0x466dec0] Unable to parse option value "bpyramid"
[aac @ 0x466dec0] Error setting option flags2 to value +bpyramid.
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

On ffmpeg version 0.10.2 it worked fine...
I need this options, what is wrong with the newest ffmpeg version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2018, those generic libavcodec options should not be used to configure libx264.

```
-flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8`
```

should be replaced with

```
-x264opts "b-pyramid=normal:weightb:mixed_refs:8x8dct"
```

Note that all of the above are set by default so you can skip them altogether.

Consider using presets. Manual tweaking of individual parameters hasn't been recommended for a long time now.

Comment: @maclin You can simplify your command even more as the [presets](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) will deal with most of it, some of your options don't apply to x264 anyway, some don't make sense, and some are default. No need to encode like it's 2006. `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 3000k -minrate 2400k -maxrate 4500k -bufsize 6000k -deinterlace -g 25 -r 25 -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4` It could be more simplified further, but I left some of your extra options in there that aren't default or preset covered.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i cant find description of what keys are apllied to each preset, if it even exists?

Comment: @maclin See `--preset` in `x264 --fullhelp`.